# Setting HTML as supported messageformat in UCWA

Tags: ucwa

I have a functional ucwa client that only works with plain messages.  According to the lync documentation, a PUT request is needed to change the supported modality and message format, and that an If-Match header is required to verify the request is not for an out-of-date status.

For example, a GET request to `/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/102628975647/communication` will return

```
{
"9b5c7fdf-2c5f-462e-a4e3-39663f09301a": "please pass this in a PUT request",
"supportedModalities": [],
"supportedMessageFormats": [
    "Plain"
],
"_links": {..},/*ommitted for brevity */
"rel": "communication",
"etag": "3010254294"
```

}

I PUT back this, with an `If-Match: 3010254294` header:

```
{
"9b5c7fdf-2c5f-462e-a4e3-39663f09301a": "please pass this in a PUT request",
"supportedModalities": [],
"supportedMessageFormats": [
    "Plain", "Html"
],
"rel": "communication",
"etag": "3010254294"
```

}

But I consistently get a `428 PreconditionRequired` error, which, according to documentation, means that I am missing the If-Match header.  Various combinations of ETag and If-Match also fail.  What is the proper format for this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember running into this issue when I was trying to figure out why I could not receive HTML-formatted messages.  The issue being that you appear to have the data correct except the If-Match header is very particular in that it would only work for me when I had the value quoted and it may/may not work for single quotes.

```
If-Match: "3010254294"
```

Relevant Fiddler Trace: [UCWA Html Messaging.saz](https://db.tt/iTngjiPh)

Comment: Thank you for the response -- that solved the negotiation issue.  This may violate format by asking a follow-up, but, when I send a message, it still shows up as literal text, literal <b> tags around the words.  Is there a formatting envelope for sending messages I am missing from the ucwa docs?

Comment: Answering my own follow-up...setting the Content-Type to text/html on outgoing messages does the trick, though it is not documented on ucwa's sendMessage page so unclear if that is officially supported